# PHP - include(); makes blank line

Tags: php, include, whitespace

Hey when I add include a file at  tag it creates a blank line (grey) like : http://puu.sh/40mvI
NOTICE: I have seen few questions like that but they didn't helped me.

```
<?php require("connection/mysql.php"); ?>
<?php @session_start(); ?>
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION["language"]))
{
    header("Location: ./language/index.php");
}
else
{
    include("./language/".$_SESSION["language"]);
}
?>
<?php if ( isset($_SESSION["bay_username"]) ) { header('Location: account/'); }?>
<!doctype html>
```

Language file

```
<?php

// NoConnect
$lg["ncon_header"]                  = "Bayyak Powered sunucularına şu an bağlanılamıyor.";
$lg["ncon_text"]                    = "Lütfen biraz sonra tekrar deneyiniz. En yakın zamanda sorunu çözeceğiz. İnternet bağlantılarınızı kontrol ediniz. Diğer aygıtlarda da aynı hatayı alıyorsanız lütfen <em>error@bayyakpowered.com</em> adresine bu sorunu bildirin.";

?>
```

Comment: Do you mean where you include a language file? There's probably whitespace in the included file causing an extra line to be created and filled with its background color.

Comment: I added language file

Comment: I don't see anything in the language file that could cause an extra line.  If you remove the inclusion, the blank line is removed too, correct?  I suggest double-checking throughout that section of code in the question for any extra white space around your `php` tags.

Comment: When I remove include() it dissapear. Someone said BOM is making that problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following:

Open your PHP file in **[Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad++), go to Format -> UTF-8 (without BOM)**

For some reason, PHP files with UTF-8 (with BOM) generate this blank line.

I advise you to convert all your PHP files.

Comment: Thank you wery much :D Bud the bad thing is I have mac so I cant download notepadd++

Comment: I see strange letters. But how to remove them? At line

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's the actual language file. But this is worth a shot anyway:

Try to omit the closing `?>` on your language file. It's allowed on files which are pure PHP (with no embedded HTML), and it can solve problems in the case where there's an invisible character after the closing bracket.

Your file should look like this:

```
<?php

// NoConnect
$lg["ncon_header"]                  = "Bayyak Powered sunucularına şu an bağlanılamıyor.";
$lg["ncon_text"]                    = "Lütfen biraz sonra tekrar deneyiniz. En yakın zamanda sorunu çözeceğiz. İnternet bağlantılarınızı kontrol ediniz. Diğer aygıtlarda da aynı hatayı alıyorsanız lütfen <em>error@bayyakpowered.com</em> adresine bu sorunu bildirin.";
```

Comment: I think this answer deserves more up votes. Solved the problem for me when the include file was pure PHP.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more clear. In order to avoid unneccessary blank lines, remove the closing php tag

```
?>
```

From the files that you include or require to your main file. You need to remove those tags in files that echo something. If you simple use for functional library, than there is no need in removing.